# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined for getting selected value in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to get the selected value from the drop down value, in alert it is showing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

can anyone help me?

```
var selectedObj = document.getElementById('selectedOption');

alert("selectedObj--->"+selectedObj);

var selectedOptionText = selectedObj.options[selectedObj.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: selectedObj.options[selectedObj.selectedIndex] is undefined thats why you are getting the error.

Comment: please log your selectedObj.selectedIndex and check if it is a accepted value inside your array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Try this `$( "#selectedOption option:selected" ).text();`

Comment: Hi can you see this link so that you will understand http://snag.gy/jEjGz.jpg

Answer (score 1):

> **selectedIndex**
>
> Technical Details
>
> Return Value:     A Number, representing the index of
> the selected option in the drop-down list. The index starts at 0. If
> no option is selected, the value returned is **-1**

So if no option is selected, you end up with `selectedObj.options[-1]`, which will always be `undefined`...

So you could do:

```
var selectedOptionText = selectedObj.selectedIndex > -1 ? selectedObj.options[selectedObj.selectedIndex].text : null;
```

If you want `selectedOptionText` to be null if no option is selected.

Or

```
var selectedIndex = selectedObj.selectedIndex;
if (selectedIndex === -1) selectedIndex = 0;
var selectedOptionText = selectedObj.options[selectedIndex].text;
```

If you want `selectedOptionText` to be equal to the first option of the select if no option is selected.

Comment: Still I am getting same error ,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined, actually I am getting selectedObj=SELECT.

Comment: I am getting index value always -1, why?

Comment: Most probably, at the time of the `var selectedIndex = selectedObj.selectedIndex;` statement, your select is empty, see http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/v4vg61xy/

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect 'selectedObj' to be? A HTML option element or a select element? This is ambiguous in the code...

```
selectedObj.options
```

implies it's the select element as does

```
selectedObj.selectedIndex
```

but

```
var selectedObj = document.getElementById('selectedOption');
```

implies this is a HTML Option element.

You need to inspect:

```
console.log(selectedObj.tagName)
```

Note using console.log() is an easier debugging option than alert().

Comment: I am getting in console when I writing like   console.log('selectedObj= '+selectedObj.tagName); o/p:  selectedObj= SELECT